# How to round 4.44445 to 4.45?

Tags: perl, rounding

Does anybody know the module which rounds not binary but as next:

```
4.444435 -> 4.44
4.444445 -> 4.45
4.445444 -> 4.45
4.443000 -> 4.44
```

The `sprintf`, `Math::BigFloat`, `Math::BigRat` can not do that =(

Comment: What are the rules?

Comment: @choroba: Here I require `.2` precision. If digit at `.3` position is 5 or greater then  - round up, if 4 then look digit at `.4` position. repeat. This is usual rules from a school

Comment: What school teaches those rules?

Comment: @Eugen Konkov -- вероятно тебе необходимо еще раз прочитать правила [округления чисел](http://files.school-collection.edu.ru/dlrstore/3e72b9a1-2e8f-4371-9c9e-f688640fe66e/section1_article6.html), [Округление](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: These rounding rules are not any I have heard of. You will probably need to write one yourself, or use one of the standard rounding methods implemented by Math::BigFloat (https://perldoc.pl/Math::BigInt#Rounding-mode-R)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still don't understand how the rules work, but playing with `bfround` from [Math::BigFloat](http://p3rl.org/Math::BigFloat) might return what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use feature qw{ say };

use Math::BigFloat;

sub myround {
    my $bi = 'Math::BigFloat'->new("$_[0]");
    for (my $l = length $bi; $l > 1; --$l) {
        $bi->bfround(-$l, '+inf');
    }
    $bi
}

use Test::More tests => 8;

is myround(4.444435), 4.44;
is myround(4.444445), 4.45;
is myround(4.445444), 4.45;
is myround(4.443000), 4.44;

is myround(3.554444), 3.55;
is myround(3.554445), 3.56;
is myround(3.544445), 3.55;
is myround(3.555550), 3.56;
```

Answer (score 0):

One of many possible solutions (although it goes against math rules)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while( <DATA> ) {
    next if /^$/;
    chomp;
    say "$_ -> " . round($_);
}

sub round {
    my $number = shift;

    my $integer  = int($number);
    my $reminder = $number - $integer;

    $reminder += $reminder < 0.444445 ? 0 : 0.001;

    $number = $integer + $reminder;

    $number = sprintf "%.2f", $number;

    return $number;
}

__DATA__
4.444435
4.444445
4.445444
4.443000
```

Output

```
4.444435 -> 4.44
4.444445 -> 4.45
4.445444 -> 4.45
4.443000 -> 4.44
```

Comment: for `4.444` result is `4.45`, but expected `4.44`. In any case thank you for suggestion.